# Cannot modify 'Accept-Encoding' with fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am trying to modify the `Accept-Encoding` header to equal `"zip"` but while I can modify or add other headers, this one is ignored. Please see the example:

```js
function printResponse(res) {
  const formatedRes = JSON.stringify(res, null, 4);
  document.getElementById('response')
    .innerHTML = formatedRes;
}

fetch('https://httpbin.org/headers', {
  headers: new Headers({
    'Accept-Encoding': 'no-difference',
    'Something-Else': 'works fine',
    'Content-Type': 'application/works-wtf'
  }),
})
.then(r => r.json())
.then(printResponse);
```

```css
#response {
  white-space: pre;  
}
```

```html
<div id="response"></div>
```

How can I modify it? Thanks

Comment: You can't, it's one of the [forbidden header names](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name). It wouldn't make much sense to change it because you can't make the client recognize an encoding just by setting a header.

Comment: Thanks @JJJ, thought it was an odd request from backend guys that it must equal exactly 'zip', they are java devs though ;) Feel free to add it as an answer

Comment: It is a reasonable thing to do if you want to disable content encoding so that you can get content-length of uncompressed resource. Otherwise content-length tells you the length after compression, which might not be what you want.